# How do I get Picasso's GrayscaleTransformation to work on Kotlin in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, picasso

I'm new to android studio and I'm working on a project of my own; I'm trying to make something grayscale with a transformation that is supposedly part of Picasso but I have no idea how to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've googled how to do this and there was very few examples of doing this in Kotlin however what I found simply said to add ".transform(GrayscaleTransformation())" after .load in my Picasso line which doesn't work and has me confused.

```
        Picasso.get()
            .load(url1)
            .transform(GrayscaleTransformation())
            .resize(size, size)
            .centerInside()
            .into(imgArt)
```

I just get an error saying Unresolved Reference: GrayscaleTransformation

Answer (score 0):

That's because Picasso doesn't have a `GrayScaleTransformation()` class. On their github repository they have a `samples` section where they implement it, but it's not part of the SDK.

If you want to just see it work with your code base copy paste their implementation (acknowledging it's from Square) into your code base

https://gist.github.com/AKiniyalocts/8545aa9ba927488adf7e